# Is there a way to calculate the stacking context of all DOM elements in order to compare any two elements for above position using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am attempting to compare any two elements in the DOM to see if they were to be painted(rendered on screen) in the same area (coordinates overlapping) which one would be above the other. This question is not about overlapping calculation, rather it is about comparing any two elements from any part of the DOM tree for above position (calculating stacking context and z-index and HTML hierarchy...).

Although I am new to this area, my approach would traverse and assign a numerical value to each HTML element taking into consideration rules and standards. Another problem is getting them correctly. I was not able to find a JS library that already does this.

For css and full code example see...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

The expected output is the ability to compare any two HTML elements for above or below position (3D). I will share my code if I get an idea from professionals here and be able to implement it. Thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to use [`document.elementsFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) which will give you all the elements, well, at given point, in stacking order.

The complicated part is that you need to find a point where both elements will intersect.

Following example will search for the top-left-most shared point, and demonstrates that you must define more precisely your constraints since it will purposely miss elements that are still in between element:

```js
test( 'red', 'blue' ); // -2 (blue:2, red:4)
test( 'red', 'green' ); // -2 (green:1, red:4) but at selected point blue is not visible
test( 'yellow', 'green' ); // -1 (yelow:3, green:1) but at selected point blue is not visible
test( 'blue', 'green' ); // -1 (blue:2, green: 1)

function test( class1, class2 ) {

  const elem1 = document.querySelector( '.' + class1 );
  const elem2 = document.querySelector( '.' + class2 );
  console.log( class1, class2, getStackDistance( elem1, elem2 ) );

}
function getStackDistance( elem1, elem2 ) {

  const shared_point = findSharedPoint( elem1, elem2 );
  if( !shared_point ) {
    console.error( 'no shared point' );
    return NaN;
  }
  const full_list = document.elementsFromPoint( shared_point.x, shared_point.y );

  return full_list.indexOf( elem1 ) - full_list.indexOf( elem2 );

}
// returns top-left-most shared point between two elements
function findSharedPoint( elem1, elem2 ) {

  const bbox1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect( elem1 );
  const bbox2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect( elem2 );
  const intersect_box = {
    left: Math.max( bbox1.left, bbox2.left ),
    right: Math.min( bbox1.right, bbox2.right ),
    top: Math.max( bbox1.top, bbox2.top ),
    bottom: Math.min( bbox1.bottom, bbox2.bottom )
  };
  if( intersect_box.left > intersect_box.right ||
    intersect_box.top > intersect_box.bottom ) {
    return null;  
  }

  return { x: intersect_box.left, y: intersect_box.top };
  
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box yellow"></div>
<div class="box green"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stacking-order) on npm called `stacking-order` that does exactly that.

You can install it with:

```sh
$ npm install stacking-order
```

```js
import stackingOrder from 'stacking-order';
```

or use https://npmcdn.com/stacking-order in a script tag.

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/stacking-order"></script>
```

Then to find what you are looking for, simply call `stackingOrder.compare(element1, element2)`

```js
const element1 = document.querySelector('#element1');
const element2 = document.querySelector('#element2');

const order = stackingOrder.compare(element1, element2);

if (order === 1)
    console.log('element1 is above element2`)
else
    console.log('element1 in under element2')
```

Comment: I find it to be a terrible approach to download something that will require you to install, rewrite all your javascript, learn a new framework, add it to your stack (with all the bugs and security issues that come with: sudo npm, eslint-scope, event-stream & is-promise, etc) - something that you by the way, most likely will not maintain or even know even a small percentage of what it really does...and for what? a standard method in just plain old javascript that you could use with var nodes = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);

Why set up hurdles and jump over them when you don't have to?

Comment: @DanielBengtsson perhaps, instead of ranting so much, you should spend your time reading the question. `document.elementsFromPoint` does not satisfy the question being asked. The question asks how to determine which of 2 elements from *ANYWHERE* within the DOM would have a higher stacking order *IF* the elements were to overlap. The stacking order spec is actually [quite complex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and having a light-weight library to handle something like this makes a lot of sense. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) It especially makes sense when the library is complex enough to not want to write your own solution, and still simple enough to look through the whole library and understand what it is doing. This library in particular also happens to be written by Rich Harris, the man behind the highly reputable Svelte framework. I see no credible reason not to use this library in this situation.